# How does the "Eclipse IDE" manipulate Windows environment "Path" variable?

Tags: eclipse, path, cmd

I have problems setting "run configuration" in Eclipse. When I use the Windows cmd to compile and run java.class I use .bat file that looks like this:

```
rem Wipe standard Windows Path variable and use this:
set PATH = C: \ Program Files \ .this path.;..and this one..;…;…

rem needed CLASSPATH's
set CLASSPATH = "... some \ path / *; ...

rem Path to native .dll libs
set LIB_PATH = "C: \ ... \ bin"

javac-cp% CLASSPATH% "... \ SomeExample.java"
java-cp% CLASSPATH%-Djava.library.path =% LIB_PATH% SomeExample
```

And everything works as it should, both compile and run are ok. When I try to do the same through Eclipse, by adjusting the classpath in run configuration GUI, compile is ok (I test it manualy in CMD), but during execution compiled class, I get java.lang. "UnsatisfiedLinkError ... someImportantDLL.dll: The specified procedure could not be found, " Which is the same error that I get while running in cmd if I do not set the PATH enviroment variable manually  in .bat file!
What should I do in Eclipse to run properly compiled class?

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct -Djava.library.path to the VM Arguments field.  Don't rely on the external environment--you should control everything about your application's environment so you won't have any "gotchas" when you roll it out.